# Telegraph Equation Subject to an Exponentially Decaying Forcing Function

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, wave-equation

Can someone please check my work for this following question? I got really complicated answer so not sure if I'm right.

Question:

> [image: question]

My work:

**Step 1: Eigenfunction Expansion of $e^{-2t}\cos(5x)$**

Eigenfunction: $$ X_n = \cos(2n+1)x, n=0,1,2,...$$

$e^{-2t} \cos(5x) = \sum^\infty _{n=0} S_n(t)\cos(2n+1)x$

$\therefore S_n(t) = e^{-2t}\delta_{n2}$

**Step2: Eigenfunction Expansion of PDE**

$u = \sum^\infty_{n=0}u_n(t)\cos(2n+1)x$

$u_{xx} = -\sum^\infty_{n=0}u_n(t)(2n+1)^2\cos(2n+1)x$

$u_{tt} = \sum^\infty_{n=0}\mathring{\mathring{u_n(t)}}\cos(2n+1)x$

$\therefore u_{tt} + 2\gamma u_t-u_{xx}-e^{-2t}\cos(5x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\cos(2n+1)x[\mathring{\mathring{u_n(t)}}+ 2\gamma \mathring{u_nt}+ u_n(t)(2n+1)^2-e^{-2t}\delta_{n2}]$

$\mathring{\mathring{u_n(t)}}+ 2\gamma \mathring{u_nt}+ u_n(t)(2n+1)^2-e^{-2t}\delta_{n2}=0$

$u_n(t) = u_p(t) + u_h(t)$

Let $u_p = Ae^{-2t}, \mathring{u_p} = -2Ae^{-2t}, \mathring{\mathring{u_p}} = 4Ae^{-2t}$

$e^{-2t}[4A-4\gamma A + A(2n+1)^2] = e^{-2t}\delta_{n2}$

$\therefore A_n = \frac{\delta_{n2}}{4-4\gamma+(2n+1)^2}$

$u(t)_h$ characteristic equation with respect to $r$.

$r^2+2\gamma r + (2n+1)^2=0$

$r= \frac{-2\gamma \pm i\sqrt{4(2n+1)-4\gamma^2}}{2}$

$\therefore u(x,t) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\cos(2n+1)x \dot [\frac{\delta_{n2}e^{-2t}}{4-4\gamma+(2n+1)^2} + e^{-\gamma t}(c_1 \cos(\sqrt{(2n+1)^2-\gamma^2))}t+ c_2\sin(\sqrt{(2n+1)^2-\gamma^2)}t)]$

Plugging in IC, we get $c_1 = \frac{-\delta_{n2}}{4-4\gamma(2n+1)^2}$

$c_2 = \frac{\delta_{n1}+\frac{\delta{n2}(2-r)}{4-4\gamma(2n+1)^2}}{\sqrt{(2n+1)^2-\gamma^2}}$

$\therefore u(x,t) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\cos(2n+1)x \dot [\frac{\delta_{n2}e^{-2t}}{4-4\gamma+(2n+1)^2} + e^{-\gamma t}(c_1 \cos(\sqrt{(2n+1)^2-\gamma^2))}t+ c_2\sin(\sqrt{(2n+1)^2-\gamma^2)}t)]$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are shown above.

Comment: I realized that I have messed up second order DE getting $c_1$ and $c_2$. Editing.

Comment: Edited all! Thank you all in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct. You could expand $n$ values and clean up a bit tho.

$$u(x,t) = \frac{\cos(3x)\sin \sqrt{9-\gamma^2}t e^{-\gamma t}}{\sqrt{(9-\gamma^2)}} + \frac{\cos(5x)}{29-4\gamma}[e^{-2t}+e^{-\gamma t}[-\cos\sqrt{25-\gamma^2}t+\frac{\sin\sqrt{25-\gamma^2}t (2-\gamma)}{\sqrt{25-\gamma^2}}]]$$